# confirm a default answer using read after a few seconds

Tags: scripts

I want to wait 3 seconds for the user to answer no. if so, then the process exits, if either user answers yes to the prompt or 3 seconds passes then y is given automatically to the question and the process continues. I tried this using read -t 3 but it complains it has not such an option.

```
 read -s -t 0 -n 9999
    read -p "Do you want to continue [DELETE on tbl_summary before \"${TM}\"] [y/s/n]? " confirm
    # ******** Saman ********
         confirm="y"
    #************************
    if [[ ${confirm} == "s" ]]; then
        kill -STOP $$
    elif [[ ${confirm} == "n" ]]; then
        exit 1
    elif [[ ${confirm} != "y" ]]; then
        echo "unknown option. exiting ..."
        exit 1
    fi
```

Comment: Your script has several mistakes e.g. you are not assigning the first input from user to a variable (the first `read`), then you have the second input assigned to `confirm` whereas in the very next line you are assigning "y" to "confirm" (then whats the point of user input?), also any of the `if` conditions won't match given "$confirm" has "y"..Please post your question more specificly..also in the first line you could do `read -s -t 3 -n 9999 somename` to assign the user input to variable `somename`..

Comment: Hope glenn jackman's answer helps you..

Comment: yes, it really did. Thank you for your comments.

Comment: Glad to hear that..please select the answer as accepted so that this issue is marked as solved..(although optional but would be nice if you also give an upvote too )..

Comment: I am very sorry, I have already created a new account,So, m not privileged to upvote for a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
read -t 3 -p "prompt: " varname    # -t to timeout in 3 seconds
: ${varname:=default value}        # set the default value if varname is null
echo "$varname"
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read